# Swift: Regex for allowing alphanumeric with one mandatory numeral

Tags: regex, swift

I am looking for a Regex satisfying the below :

- Alphanumeric is allowed with min and max limit.
- Atleast 1 numeral is mandatory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example (best would be a Playground code snippet).

Comment: If you were to provide some examples (both of strings you'd be searching and the type of patterns you're looking for) it would help people get you a more accurate answer. As the question stands now, I'd ask something like "Does the mandatory number have to be in a specific position", or "How many alphanumerics are allowed"? So need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of alphanumeric in a string using the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and limit the minimum and maximum occurrences using `{8,13}`. You can also make sure there is at least one digit doing a positive lookahead pattern for digits `(?=.*\\d)` and non digits `(?=.*\\D)`:

```
let regex = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\D)([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,13})$"
```

**Regex details**

> ^ asserts position at start of the string
>
> (?=.*\d) • Positive lookahead that matches any character that's a
>   digit
>
> (?=.*\D) • Positive lookahead that matches any character thats a
>   non-digit
>
> ([a-zA-Z0-9]) • First capturing group that matches any alphanumeric character
>
> {8,13} • limits occurrences of the preciding token (from 8 to 13)
>
> $  asserts position at end of the string

```
let string = "abcdefg1"

if let range = string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) {
    print(string[range])  // abcdefg1\n"
}
```